# Morphism of varieties proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

If we consider matrix multiplication on $\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\times \text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\to \text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)$, how do I show this is a morphism of varieties?

I know that this is the vanishing of $(x_{11}x_{22}-x_{12}x_{21})q-1 \in K[x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},q]$, where the entries are labelled how you probably expect:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I check it is a morphism of varieties?

I can see the entries give us:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}&x_{12}\\x_{21}&x_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}'&x_{12}'\\x_{21}'&x_{22}'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}x_{11}'+x_{12}x_{21}'&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot\end{bmatrix}$$

So the four entries are just polynomials in the entries of the original matrices, I feel like the it's regular on the entries, but not sure how to say rigorously that this is a morphism of varieties.

Comment: There is nothing more to say, this is polynomial in the coordinates of $GL_2$ as you said, so it's a morphism.

Comment: @N.H. Should I really say this:
$$\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\times\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\subset \Bbb A^{10},$$
and we see $\psi(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},x_{11}',\dots,x_{22}',q,q')=(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\phi_3(x),\phi_4(x),w(x))$, and $\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_4,w\in \Bbb{C}[\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\times\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)]$ so this is a morphism of affine varieties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt self answer:

$$\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\times\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\subset \Bbb A^{10},$$
and we see $$\psi(x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22},x_{11}',\dots,x_{22}',q,q')=(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\phi_3(x),\phi_4(x),w(x)),$$ and $$\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_4,w\in \Bbb{C}[\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)\times\text{GL}(2,\Bbb C)]$$ so this is a morphism of affine varieties

Comment: Exactly ! +1 ${{}}$